# Append to List while Iterating

Tags: python, list, iteration

I need this behavior, but would rather have a diminishing list rather than a growing one.
Sequence order is important for this operation.

```
for item in mylist:
    if is_item_mature(item):
        ## Process him
    else:
        ## Check again later
        mylist.append(item)
```

but I would rather have it more like this. Does this behave like I think? Any better ways?

```
while mylist:
    item = list.pop(0)
    if is_item_mature(item):
        ##Process
    else:
        mylist.append(item)
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like it behaves like you think. But does it work like you expected it to work?

Comment: `list` is not a good choice of variable name.

Comment: All seems well, only hiccup was a deadlock on some of the last items (Part of my dataset was in error). Debugger caught the Queue chasing its tail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only problem I see with your approach is a growing list that depending upon your usage may eat up your memory

I would rather suggest you to use a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). Queue is designed and flexible enough to handle both ended production and consumption

```
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue() #You can also specify the maximum size of the Queue here
# Assume your Queue was filled
while not q.empty():
    # It won;t block if there are no items to pop
    item = q.get(block = False) 
    if is_item_mature(item):
        #process
    else:
        #In case your Queue has a maxsize, consider making it non blocking
        q.put(item)
```

Comment: I think I like this as well. My loop processing is a bit crude at the moment, and strict sequencing saves me from some extra code for the time being.

Comment: `Queue.Queue` is for multithreading. If you don't need this, just use `collections.deque`, which is internally used by Queue.

Answer (score 9):

You can safely append items to the list, and the iteration will include those items:

```
>>> lst = range(5)
>>> for i in lst:
...     print i
...     if i < 3:
...         lst.append(i + 10)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
10
11
12
```

However, if you prefer a diminishing list, then your `while` loop is perfectly suitable for your needs.

Comment: How do you know this is safe and works like that? Is that documented somewhere? I've been trying to find some proof for this for a long time...

Comment: @StefanPochmann: How do I know? Experience and knowledge of the list and list iterator implementation details. It's not explicitly documented.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: the list iterator returned by `iter(list)` stores a current position (an integer) and a reference to the list. Each time you get the next element, the current position is checked against the current list size, and if it is smaller, the item at the current position is retrieved from the list, the position incremented, and the retrieved item is returned.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: this makes it safe to extend or shrink the list; the length is tested each time. The position is incremented regardless of what happened to the list in the interim, which is why it is often a bad idea to *remove* elements at or before the current position (the contents shift but the current position is not adjusted accordingly).

Comment: Thanks. Though that's what I knew/suspected already. Recently I even used this in a `for x in a` loop where I wanted to "skip" the next element after certain `x` values, so for such values I called `a.pop(0)`. But that's because I'm currently coding only for fun. I wouldn't use that or even "append during iteration" in serious code, because I can't trust it. I find it conceivable that the iterator looks up and stores the list size when it's created, or checks index against size *after* retrieving an item, or does some other unexpected thing. As far as I know, I ...

Comment: ... can't be certain that every Python implementation does it the way you describe, not even future CPython versions. And whenever I post some code using this on stackoverflow or similar sites, I somewhat feel bad for teaching people something I know I don't know is safe, and I'd never call it safe. That's why I was hoping you had something more concrete.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'm pretty sure too much production code relies on this for the CPython folks ever to break this now. :-) For skipping items, use `seqiter = iter(seq)` then in a `for item in seqiter:` loop you can skip arbitrary items with `next(seqiter)`. :-)

Comment: Well then they could as well just document it to make it official so I can sleep better :-). Yeah, I've used iter+next for skipping before, but that's more code and I wanted it short there. (You btw have a typo, item(seq) -> iter(seq))