# Set changes implicit order based on __hash__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, set, python-internals

I've just observed an interesting behavior of a Set in Python3 and am wondering why.

Given the class:

```
class Tab:

    @staticmethod
    def set(size):
        return set(map(lambda label: Tab(label), range(1, size + 1)));

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.up = True

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Tab):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.label == other.label

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.label)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.label)
```

When I invoke `Tab.set(9)` I get a set of tabs that, when represented as a string via:

```
"|%s|" % "|".join([str(tab) for tab in self.tabs])
```

Generates:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
```

However, if I only modify `__eq__` and `__hash__` to incorporate the `up` attribute:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Tab):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.label == other.label and self.up == other.up

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.label, self.up))
```

The implicit ordering of the set changes, and the string representation becomes:

```
|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|
```

I understand that sets are not ordered. But why did the implicit ordering change, when the static `set` method is unchanged, creating each element in the set from 1 through 9, just as before?

And, what might I do to preserve the implicit ordering so my set appears to be in order, just as before? (Note that the change is caused by the change in `__hash__` and not `__eq__`.)

Comment: but your `set` method has to use `__hash__` internally

Comment: why don't you just sort your set when you need it sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why did the implicit ordering change

Because `set` is implemented as [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in CPython. So:

- The slot where an item is stored in the `set` depends on the (truncated) hash of the item (and to some extend the insertion order because the slot may be already occupied).
- The hash of the item depends on the [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method of that item.

And if you iterate over the `set` you iterate over the hashtable (excluding missing entries) slot-by-slot. So by changing the hashes you *may* change the order.

And in your case the hashes are different because you changed the `__hash__` method implementation, so it's to be expected that the order is different:

```py
>>> [hash(tab) for tab in Tab.set(9)]  # first code
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> [hash(tab) for tab in Tab.set(9)]  # second code
[3713072971709512581, 3713088127104978631, 3713071889183430056, 3713087044578896106, 3713083796991988331, 3713082714465905806, 3713085962048483481, 3713084879522400956, 3713081631935493181]
```

> what might I do to preserve the implicit ordering so my set appears to be in order, just as before

If you want them to be ordered my suggestion would be to **not use a `set`** - use an ordered collection, just to name one example: `list`. There are also ways to efficiently [remove duplicates from a list and preserving the order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/5393381).

But if you want to keep the `set` and want them to be sorted by the `label` property you could also use `sorted`:

```
sorted(tab.set(9), key=lambda t: t.label)

>>> [str(t) for t in sorted(Tab.set(9), key=lambda t: t.label)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

---

## Inspecting the CPython 3.7.4 hashtable using Cython

Note: This is inspecting implementation details which may change across versions. The Cython code may not even work for different CPython versions. **Don't take them literally and never ever depend on them.**

In case you're interested how the actual implementation details of CPython look like, you can use this Cython helper for Jupyter I've written in [this answer to "Updating a set while iterating over its elements"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129438/5393381):

```
%load_ext Cython
%%cython

from cpython cimport PyObject, PyTypeObject
cimport cython

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    ctypedef Py_ssize_t Py_hash_t

    struct setentry:
        PyObject *key
        Py_hash_t hash

    ctypedef struct PySetObject:
        Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt
        PyTypeObject *ob_type
        Py_ssize_t fill
        Py_ssize_t used
        Py_ssize_t mask
        setentry *table
        Py_hash_t hash
        Py_ssize_t finger

        setentry smalltable[8]
        PyObject *weakreflist

cpdef print_set_table(set inp):
    cdef PySetObject* innerset = <PySetObject *>inp
    for idx in range(innerset.mask+1):
        if (innerset.table[idx].key == NULL):
            print(idx, '<EMPTY>')
        else:
            print(idx, innerset.table[idx].hash, <object>innerset.table[idx].key)
```

This will print the internal hashtable, each line contains the slot number, the hash and the stored item.

In the first case:

```
>>> print_set_table(Tab.set(9))
0 <EMPTY>
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 9
10 <EMPTY>
11 <EMPTY>
[...]
30 <EMPTY>
31 <EMPTY>
```

Second case:

```
>>> print_set_table(Tab.set(9))
0 <EMPTY>
[...]
4 <EMPTY>
5 3713072971709512581 9
6 <EMPTY>
7 3713088127104978631 7
8 3713071889183430056 8
9 <EMPTY>
10 3713087044578896106 6
11 3713083796991988331 3
12 <EMPTY>
13 <EMPTY>
14 3713082714465905806 2
15 <EMPTY>
[...]
24 <EMPTY>
25 3713085962048483481 5
26 <EMPTY>
27 <EMPTY>
28 3713084879522400956 4
29 3713081631935493181 1
30 <EMPTY>
31 <EMPTY>
```

Comment: So in other words, when hashing on just the int, which matches my own conceptual ordering of ints, I've gotten "lucky" with the implicit ordering.

Comment: @ybakos To some extend yes, it's because the hash of integers is just the integer (except for -1) and you also inserted them in-order. In case you're really interested in the implementation details (which may change across versions, so think of them as just-for-fun) I've added Cython code to introspect the set-internals.

Comment: Super awesome answer @MSeifert!

Answer (score 2):

> why did the implicit ordering change, when the static `set` method is unchanged, creating each element in the set from 1 through 9, just as before?

This method is unchanged, but calls built-in `set` with `Tab` objects.

And since the `__hash__` method has changed, `set` may change the internal order which you should not rely on anyway.

What would work in your case would be to sort when printing:

```
"|%s|" % "|".join([str(tab) for tab in sorted(self.tabs,lambda t:(t.label, t.up)])
```

or without lambda, define a `__lt__` method so `sort` can compare objects

Comment: Gosh, when have you become a moderator?! Congratulations! Feel free to remove the comment when you've read it. :-) Btw: Nice idea with the `__lt__`.

Comment: thanks, you have missed the 2019 march elections it seems :)