# Add a prefix to all set items

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have a `defaultdict(set)` like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'key1': {'val1'}, 'key2': {'val2', 'val3'}})
```

I want to add a prefix say `foo-` to values of `key2`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'key1': {'val1'}, 'key2': {'foo-val2', 'foo-val3'}})
```

How would I do that?

I did a for loop like this:

```py
for i in my_set["key2"]:
    i_new = "foo-"+i
    my_set["key2"].remove(i)
    my_set["key2"].add(i_new)
```

But this results in: `'key2': {'foo-val2', 'foo-foo-val3'}`

Comment: Don't add/remove items from a collection while you're iterating over it.  This causes the actual contents to get out of sync with the iterator loop, and Mysterious Things happen as a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a set while iterating over its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018680/updating-a-set-while-iterating-over-its-elements)

Comment: @amoralesc That question is asking for an explanation of such behavior. Also if you think the question should be closed, then you shouldn't be answering it.

Comment: @gre_gor I don't think that flagging as possible duplicate while also providing an answer is bad etiquette, since the answers will still be available right? Still, I think it's important to show to OP _why_ their approach is incorrect, how can they fix it, and point people in the right direction when they google a similar question

Comment: @amoralesc [No, it's not ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341654)

Comment: @gre_gor Fairly ironic that that question was closed as a duplicate. But I understand the motivation now. I will aim to do only one or the other in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the set in-place, create a new one.

```
my_set["key2"] = set(f"foo-{i}" for i in my_set["key2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This great answer by [@MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129438/21323912) illustrates why modifying a set (or any collection for that matter) while iterating over it is such a bad idea.

As [@gre_gor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78031617/21323912) suggested, just create a new set from the old one.

Another approach (not using list comprehension):

```py
new_set = {}
for i in my_set["key2"]:
    new_set.add(f"foo-{i}")
my_set["key2"] = new_set
```