# Python: Iterating over a list, but I want to add to that list while in the loop and continue iterating over what was added.

Tags: python, loops, iterable

Just trying to do something like this. I want to keep appending to lst, and keep iterating over what was added.

```
lst = [secondLst]

for i in lst:

    *some code*

    lst.append(x)
```

And i would eventually reach x in the for loop.

Is this possible? 
Is there a better way?

Comment: You could use `collections.deque`, using `pop` and `append` on different sides.

Comment: Did it not work when you tried it?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, it didnt. Im not really sure why not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works fine.  Internally, Python maintains a list index, increments it by 1 on each iteration, and checks it anew against the then-current length of the list each time.  The list length is *not* captured at the very start of the loop.  So, for example:

```
>>> L = [10, 20, 30]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(L):
...     print(v)
...     if i < 3:
...         L.append(i)

10
20
30
0
1
2
```

It may be clearer to do it more explicitly, though.  For example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = [10, 20, 30]
>>> extras = []
>>> for i, v in enumerate(itertools.chain(L, extras)):
...     print(v)
...     if i < 3:
...         extras.append(i)
```

You can [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> Note: There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be treated again the next time through the loop.

Comment: This is incorrect. `enumerate` makes a copy of the list and you will not be iterating over the addition too.

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai, not so.  Run the code.  It works fine.  `enumerate()` copies nothing.  If you're the one who down-voted this answer, you should retract it ;-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann, see the edit just now for a doc reference.  It's explicitly pointing out what can go _wrong_, but you can also infer from it the behavior I already described.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good approach.  Based on OP's original code, it seems they want to add directly to the `list` being iterated.  In this case it'll easily create an infinite loop as the index will never reach the end.  I think it's important to point out the use of your `if i < 3:` just so OP doesn't run into an infinite loop.

Comment: @TimPeters Hmm, that does sound rather convincing. A while ago I tried hard to find it documented properly but failed. Martijn Pieters also seemed to not be aware of that note when I [asked him recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175732/append-to-list-while-iterating#comment82521107_15175745). Not sure I haven't seen this note before or did but still didn't trust it fully. It doesn't say when exactly the counter-vs-length check is done and I thought it *could* be done right after taking an element, before giving it to the loop body, so an `append` when you're already at the ...

Comment: ... last element would be lost because the loop already decided that this is the last iteration. But I guess the repeat-current-if-insert-before implies that that's not how it's done, as that wouldn't be true for the last element. Still, I'd prefer it mention `append` as well, that's the in-loop-modification that I use the most and I suspect I'm not alone with that. It's also not reassuring that the author thinks that only lists are mutable sequences (or that they don't know what "i.e." means).

Comment: @StefanPochmann, why not open a bug report on the docs?  Same as Martijn, this is something the old-time Python devs "all know", and there's no chance it will be changed.  Too much code relies on the append behavior; e.g., here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696836/implement-kahns-topological-sorting-algorithm-using-python/43702281#43702281

Comment: @StefanPochmann, FYI, I opened a bug report for this: https://bugs.python.org/issue32767

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't occur to me to open a bug report. And I wasn't sure it's not documented (plus I now know it somewhat is) and I couldn't have done it as well as you now did, and I'm not important ;-)